# One to many join and group by id in the 'one' table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: Person and events where Person has many events

I want to join the tables by person.id but I don't want the query to return a record per event. Instead I want it to return a record per person with many events attached to it. Is this possible?

For example I get:

```
["person_id" : "1", "eventid" :"1"]
["person_id" : "1", "eventid" :"2"]
["person_id" : "1", "eventid" :"3"]
```

But what I want is

```
["person_id" : "1", ["eventid" :"1", "eventid" :"2", "eventid" :"3"]]
```

Comment: Post some sample data in your original post, with what you expect the output to be as a result.

Comment: So you want the result returned as JSON?

Comment: no that's just my way of representing the how the results is structured

Comment: The way this is worded it appears you're looking for an SQL answer... Are you using this in any particular language outside of SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select person.id, array_agg(eventid)
from person
 inner join events
 on person.id = events.person_id
group by person_id
```

Comment: Thanks the event table has around 40 columns i need tor return. Can this be done with the array_agg function?

Comment: I did not understand, what is "tor"?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comments inline, when using group by we can use functions like sum() to add integers, your basic issue is to concat strings on group by, which is kind of not direct.

```
--This is how would I do in MS SQL 
--Person-Event Data
CREATE TABLE #person (person_id INT, event_id INT)

INSERT INTO #person
SELECT 1,1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1

--Concept is to use Group By and concat strings in inner query
--Inner query is on same table as outer table,
--using group by column of outer query in where clause of inner query to filter results
--STUFF(string, start index, length of string which is to be replaced, replace with string)
--used stuff to remove the leading comma 
SELECT person_id, pevents=STUFF((
                SELECT ',' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),event_id)
                FROM #person pinner 
                WHERE pinner.person_id=pouter.person_id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
--bonus formatting, dont know if you need this          
,  pevents_formatted=STUFF((
                SELECT ',' +'"eventid" : "' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),event_id)+'"'
                FROM #person pinner 
                WHERE pinner.person_id=pouter.person_id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'[ ')+' ]'    


            ,person_with_pevents_formatted_result=  '[ "personid" :"'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),person_id)+'" ,' +   
            STUFF((
                SELECT ',' +'"eventid" : "' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),event_id)+'"'
                FROM #person pinner 
                WHERE pinner.person_id=pouter.person_id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'[ ')+' ] ]'


FROM #person pouter
GROUP BY  person_id

DROP TABLE #person
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @jon lee I saw you mentioned about multiple columns in other comment, You can use FOR XML PATH('') in inner query in same way, for multiple column to build whatever string you want.